# LUIS Batch Testing for Entity is Not Working

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

Referring to the [batch testing document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-batch-testing) from Microsoft, I have [imported the LUIS app](https://github.com/Microsoft/LUIS-Samples/blob/master/documentation-samples/quickstarts/custom-domain-review-HumanResources.json) provided from this document and import this [this JSON batch file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-batch-testing#create-batch-file-with-entities) to LUIS batch testing panel and try to run the test.

The testing result of 'Intents' is as expected, however, for the 'Entities', it is expected some of the entities will pass but at the end all entities are failed:
[Entities Fail Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie7Kc.png)

Is it a bug in LUIS or anything going wrong?

Updates: The issue above is fixed but some batch testing function are still not working

After the fix have been released, I have tried it again. I found that it works fine with no entity, simple entity and hierarchical entity. However, for List Entity and Regex Entity still not working on Microsoft sample. [Entity list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYXg5.png) and [entity list in batch testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8kqC.png) in Microsoft sample are not match. Besides, in my own Luis project, the list entity is showing in the batch testing entity list but the result is strange [(caption in this screen cap)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7rxx.png).

Comment: just repro'd your steps. It does seem like a bug...pinging the LUIS dev team to verify

Comment: Indeed it is a bug, and has been reported. We will work towards a resolution. Thank you for bringing the matter to our attention

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Hope that it can be fixed asap.

Comment: @ Eric, a fix was deployed over the weekend. Is everything working alright for you now?

Comment: @Zeryth thank you very much for fixing the issue. The original issue have been fixed but there are still some bugs in batch testing. Please kindly see the above updates.

Comment: Eric are the issues still persisting for you? There have been more pushes made with regards to batch entities

Comment: @Zeryth It works perfectly now! Thanks for fixing it :)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you look at the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-batch-testing), it is stated that:

*"Only the machine-learned entities are used: simple, hierarchical (parent-only), and composite entities. Do not add non-machine-learned entities because they are always found either through regular expressions, or explicit text matches"*

And List Entities are not machine-learned entities.